# not able to write the data in single column of excel row-wise in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I want to save the data in a single column row-wise, but at every time I save, a new cell is created and the data is not saved anymore in a single column.

Can you help me please ?

Thank you all.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/dev2/Downloads/newchromedriver/chromedriver");
        WebDriver m = new ChromeDriver();
        m.get("https://.130:2096/");
        m.manage().window().maximize();
        m.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='user']")).sendKeys("talconnect.com.au");
        m.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='pass']")).sendKeys("$}+FdVI5$o!G");
        m.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@id='login_submit']")).click();
        m.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // m.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2,TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        m.switchTo().frame("mailFrame");
        Thread.sleep(9000);

        List<WebElement> xpath11 = m.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr[contains(@id, 'rcmrow')]"));

        int count = xpath11.size();
        System.out.println(count);
        for (WebElement link : xpath11) {
            String sd = link.getText();
            File source = new File("/home/dev2/Desktop/readexcell.xlsx");
            FileOutputStream input = new FileOutputStream(source);
            XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sheet=wb.createSheet("data");

                 int i;


            for(i=0; i<=count; i++) {
                XSSFRow excelRow = sheet.createRow(i);
                XSSFCell excelCell = excelRow.createCell(i); 
                excelCell.setCellType(CellType.STRING); 
                excelCell.setCellValue(sd);  
            }

            input.flush();
            wb.write(input);
```

Comment: i have also tried Read_xls reader but the eclipse is not able to recognize reader instead of it its  showing XSSF and xssfb reader option

Comment: You need to work on the for loop logic. you are using the same `i` variable inside loop. which will create something like 0,0 1,1 2,2 3,3  . But before that, why are you looping inside a loop . Either go with for each or for..i . not both.

Comment: now I am able to print the data in single column row by row by just mentioning the cell number "zero" i.e XSSFCell excelCell = excelRow.createCell(0) in the above code. but the issue I have 50 records out of which only last record is  written 50 times in excel  can u plz help